# Spring MongoRepository pagination performance

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using spring boot base application ,its has get all record method with pagination

```
public interface AssignmentRepository extends MongoRepository<Assignment, String> {

Page<Assignment> findBySectionIdAndDelete(String sectionId, Boolean delete, Pageable pageable); }
```

since this method execution  i notice some performance  degradation ,
and i added some debug log and print mongo query

```
2016-02-08 17:40:08 DEBUG MongoTemplate:1635 - find using query: { "sectionId" : "55b1c4e3e4b0d89510c6aa27" , "delete" : false} fields: null for class: class com.era.core.domain.Assignment in collection: assignment
```

Assignment collection  indexes

> sectionId,delete

My Questions is,
Is this pagination happening on database or Application (Mongo Repository) level?

Comment: I guess it's issuing a count query in order to populate the `Page` properly.

Comment: @Ali Can you explain bit more ,thanks

Comment: `Page` should knows about total number of pages. So, any call to a that method would issue two queries: first one is a count query and the second one is the actual query

Comment: It's the default behavior in Spring Data JPa and i'm guessing same is true for mongodb

Comment: Did you try `Slice<Assignment>` instead of `Page<Assignment>`?

Comment: @AliDehghani i pass the page size and offset  wrap with page parameter,

Comment: I know. but when you specify the return type as `Page<T>` instead of `Slice<T>`, it will execute two queries. Use `Slice<Assignment>` instead of `Page<Assignment>` and see what happens.